# Word(s) or synonyms for excessive justice?

Tags: word-choice

There are many euphemisms when talking about the concept of "excessive justice", "dark justice", "extreme justice" and so forth. Justice taken to the extreme, to the detriment of all other virtues. I'm wondering if there is a simpler word, a single word, for this meaning - or something close to it. A desire to impose justice harshly and ruthlessly - that's the meaning, I suppose.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can talk about excessive justice if you want to. But it is not "a thing" until you define it. /Justice taken to an extreme, to the detriment of all other virtues/ does express it. Once you have explained that, in a written piece, you can say excessive justice because  YOU have defined it. However, then you say: impose justice harshly, which is a completely different idea. Justice is served or not served in English, generally speaking. It is not imposed.

Comment: Right, so I wasn't entirely clear in my wording. But are you saying that you don't know of any single words that relate to what I asked, or are you just making a statement that justice is relative?

Comment: It's a bit like asking for a word for excessive truth. Justice is justice. it is an absolute.

Comment: @Mikael Malmberg  I think my comment was clear. It is not a pre-existing notion at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single word to mean "excessive punishment", however, there are forms of punishment which may be considered excessive, usually the mention of

> [corporal punishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporal_punishment) is a punishment intended to cause physical pain on a person. It is usually inflicted in settings with a substantial disparity of power between the partakers.

carries this weight, since it is considered a form of harsh punishment.

> The teen spitting gum in Singapore may face corporal punishment.
>   *the teen in Singapore may be flogged for spitting gum*.

Comment: Yes, the OP probably meant excessive punishment. Rather than justice.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I did. Sorry for not making that clear in the beginning, I'm generally very fluent in the language but as we can see, I've still got some holes in my understanding of it. I've also been in a fever the whole week, so I'm not at my best either!